# Raspberry pi run startup python script cannot send HTTP requests

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, python-requests, startup

I let my python script run at startup but some of HTTP requests (using `requests` pip module) not working. However, when I run the script manually with `sudo openvt -s -w /path/to/launcher.sh`, all HTTP requests are working fine.

this is my code in`~/.bashrc`

```
sudo openvt -s -w /path/to/launcher.sh
```

and in `launcher.sh`, it is as simple as `cd` to directory and run python script.

```
cd /path/to/python/script
python start.py
```

when the script is run at startup. HTTP requests throw this error:

```
ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /my/api (Caused by <class 'socket.gaierror'>: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution)
```

Again, when I run the script via `ssh` using this command `sudo openvt -s -w /path/to/launcher.sh`, everything is working fine. I'm struggling this bugs for days. Thank you so much for any  helps :)

Comment: Talking about sartup, do you mean at the boot time, or when you log in ?

Comment: I configured raspberry pi to boot to CLI with auto login, so yes when I log in